# Django: How to reference a AutoField?

Tags: sql, django, model

I have a data model like this:

```
class MaterialType(models.Model):
    materialType_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    materialType_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    parentNode_id = models.IntegerField()
```

The third row in the class wants to reference to another materialType's id, just like in the first row. but the first row is an AutoField, I guess I could use IntegerField to reference it?

Could you give some hint to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a relation field, like a foreign key:

```
parentNode_id = models.ForeignKey(
    'self', 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='parents'
)
```

By default, Django add this on the primary key field, so in your case materialType_id. The `related_name` is the name of the foreign key on your instance.